# How is made the integration between an application and a website?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone, integration

I have been a Windows Phone developer for a year and a half, but I have never made an application to collect and send data to web, for lack of knowledge, I know that the question is kind of vague, but do not know where to start, where do I start the studies?

I want to know how the application integrates with any website, as customer social media, which collect and send posts, and applications that collect news portals and organize the application.

Comment: Depending on what you want to do you could look into databases (SQL) or APIs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer - is You need a WebApi

A very good place to start would be here
http://www.asp.net/web-api

The simple and BAD approach - is to let Your phone access the Database directly over the internet. It's bad (or not recommended) due to security, scalability as manageability concerns